# Why this thread freezes my app on destruction?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm sure it's related to the GetMessage call as if I replace it with 'while(not terminated) do;', the app'd close peacefully. Is it because GetMessage freezes the thread? Could you give more info about the problem itself and eventually a solution. Thanks!

```
type TListener = class(TThread)
  procedure Execute; override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

var l: TListener;
    msg:TMsg;

procedure TListener.Execute;
begin
  while(not Terminated) do
    while(GetMessage(msg, Cardinal(-1), 0, 0)) do;
end;

destructor TListener.Destroy;
begin
  inherited; // <-- freeze here!
end;

begin
  l:= TListener.Create();
  sleep(1000);
  l.Free;
end.
```

Comment: Well, either Terminated is never being set to "true" or else GetMessage is a blocking call, or else GetMessage is constantly returning a value that evaluates to "true." I don't know delphi, so you'll need to figure out which of these three it is.

Comment: I'd go with the second. But where's the problem?

Comment: What does Getmessage do and why are you doing a nested while loop on it (while within another while)?

Comment: If this is all the code, `Terminated` will never be set. He should call `l.Terminate` and then wait for it to end, before he frees it.

Comment: @Warren: `GetMessage()` is a Win32 API function that retrevies a message from the calling thread's message queue.  If there is no message, it blocks until a message arrives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the termination condition of your inner loop. `GetMessage` blocks until a message arrives, and it only returns `False` when it processes a `wm_Quit` message.

The thread that calls `Free` on your `TThread` is waiting for the other thread to terminate — `TThread.Destroy` calls `WaitFor`. But your thread never terminates because it evidently never receives a `wm_Quit` message.

Since you're already using messages, don't bother checking `Terminated`. That only checks whether someone has called `Terminate` on your thread object, but since doing so clearly isn't the way to notify the thread that it should stop running, it's pointless to check it. (If the `Terminate` method were virtual, you could override it and have it post a `wm_Quit` message to the thread, but it isn't, so you can't.)

Comment: I thought Terminate()'d destroy the thread, but it only sets a variable to true. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I just submitted a QC request about that yesterday. If you'd like a virtual `TThread.Terminate`, go ahead and vote for http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=97180